# I need help with this number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Okay, so I was reading my local newspaper, and they had an article about a pub quiz, which had the following sequence:

> 762 - 774 - 571 - 742 - 629 - 796 - 794 - 861

And the question was to figure out the next two numbers. They provided the answers (see spoiler below) but I can't figure out what the reasoning behind it is. 
Usually, I'm quite capable of figuring these things out, and I get annoyed whenever there are lots of possible ways to continue the series. But now I can't even figure out any logic, let alone the one for the correct answer.

I've tried analyzing the difference between the numbers, differences between the digits of the numbers, checking if there are two or three series mixed together... I dunno, I'm probably missing somthing here.

Does anybody here have a clue?

The correct numbers are

> 719 and 643

according to the newspaper.

Comment: Are you sure there is no missing info to solve this? Was this taken from a dutch news paper? If anyone can understand dutch, they might be interested in the following link... god knows google translate does not comprehend dutch at all. But from what I could make out, it seemed like there might have been a trivial aspect to the chain... https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2017/06/30/hele-dorpen-lopen-uit-voor-de-dorpsquiz-11367149-a1565096

Comment: This might be one of those puzzles like JFMAMJJASOND or MTWTFSS where you need to know some common knowledge that can't be figured out from the puzzle itself. Could these be the lengths of words in first-middle-last names of famous people, or the lenghts of words of popular poems/songs/phrases?

Comment: @stackreader, there is no extra information in the article. It just shows a couple of questions that you can find in a pubquiz. that's probably why google fails to translate it properly.

Comment: @stackreader Yeah that's where I got the sequence from. No extra information there. I could figure any months or weekday things in there. Maybe there was some extra information they omitted in the article, perhaps I'll contact the editors of the article.

Comment: I've been taking a look at this over the past three days with no success. It's killing me. The possible answer I've found that I'm 99% sure is not correct is: there are 5 even numbers, 3 odds, add two odd numbers to make it 5/5. This only really works if you bend [the definition for aanvullen](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/aanvullen). I am convinced there is supplemental information we are not privy to.

Comment: All the numbers are between 500 and 900. The second and third digits are all over the show, which suggests these are to be read as numbers in a limited range. Perhaps numbers associated with something that's ordered alphabetically, or as the above commenter mentions, like months or days if the week.

Comment: Where was this newspaper published? Could it be monthly rain fall or some other such thing associated with your location. Googling the numbers revealed a very boring looking book with tables on the motion of the earth on it's axis. Something with a limited range, anyway...

Comment: @DrXorile The newspaper was just a national Dutch newspaper. But the article got it from a pub quiz from the southern part of the country. Could be something like local precipitation, but I can't find matching numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - with the helpful addition of more information from the puzzle's creator, we can now see that the sequence continues:

> **719 - 643 - 694 - 684**

The sequence is

> the scores for each team in the contest, in order by team number.
>  Team 1 finished in 9th place with a score of 762, team 2 scored 774, and so on.  The scores for teams 1-8 were provided in the original sequence.  I've provided the next 4.  The other 15 can be read off the score chart provided by [@Neils Dirks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55236/30633).

Answer (score 7):

I am the maker of this question and first I want to say that I like the fact that this question made it to the internet. Second, you could not have known the answer to this question as it used the results of the 'Dorps Quiz' (Village Quiz) of 2016. This question was asked in the edition of 2017. I have attached these results, so I think you are able to finish the sequence now! [image] (Eersel is the village where the quiz took place, it is a nice, beautiful village in the south of The Netherlands, so feel free to visit it ;)).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for responding and too bad the newspaper didn't mention something like this.